# Only show specified id inside the IN clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
    SELECT * FROM `charges`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `confinement`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `ultrasound` 
WHERE procedure_no IN (100, 200)
ORDER BY FIELD(procedure_no,100,200);
```

THe first part of the sql command is where i'm joining 3 tables of charges. they're all the same but just different context. I want that command to show only the procedure numbers 100 and 200. So only 2 results. But it shows in mysql a lot of results.

this is the result 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2STXD.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you have posted essentially does three queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `charges`

SELECT * FROM `confinement`


SELECT * FROM `ultrasound` WHERE procedure_no IN (100, 200) ORDER BY FIELD(procedure_no,100,200);
```

I.e. Currently only the ultrasounds are filtered by procedure no. Try (untested):

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `charges`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `confinement`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `ultrasound` ) AS t1
WHERE t1.procedure_no IN (100, 200)
ORDER BY FIELD(t1.procedure_no,100,200);
```

Basic SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1f08/1

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have guessed that.